# asp.net:CustomValidator - Not Firing First

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, customvalidator

I've got my custom validator working, the only problem is its not firing before anything else, its happening at the same time. Yes, I am getting my error message when a parameter is not met, but I am also getting the rest of my application. I would like nothing to even happen yet until said parameter is met.

Here's what I mean:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbLocation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valMatchLocation" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbLocation" 
     ErrorMessage="Please include date or date range." OnServerValidate="valMatchLocation_ServerValidate">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

And my code behind:

```
Protected Sub valMatchLocation_ServerValidate(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
        Dim current_user = CurrentUser.AuthenticatedData.Get_CurrentUser

        If (args.Value = current_user.Id) Then
            args.IsValid = True

        Else
            args.IsValid = False

        End If
    End Sub
```

When testing, this does indeed do part of what I want; however, this validation does not happen prior to the rest of the application. ex: user wants to search for some documents not pertaining to that users specific Id, so if user inputs an Id that is not theirs, they must then meet other parameters before the search can actually progress.

Please help. I'm getting very frustrated. Although, I'm sure its something stupid I'm missing :{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used custom validator's client side validation?

You can use something like this :

VB Code:

```
valMatchLocation.ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateSomething";
valMatchLocation.EnableClientScript = true;
```

Javascript:

```
function ValidateSomething(sender, args)
{
    //Your code here   
    //if (condition)
    { //satisfied
        args.IsValid = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

This could solve your problem as the validation happens before the postback to the server.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hmmm I don't think I've used the client side. Now the javascript takes place in the front end, but my questions is the VB code you provided, does that replace my Protected Sub in my back end? or does my original back end code that I have not change and I simply add something along the lines of what you provided?

Comment: The above VB code is an addition. It does not replace your protected sub method. What you would be doing is adding both client side validation and server side validation. Its a good practice to have both client-side validation and server-side validation.

Comment: The above VB code should go into your page_load event or the place where you have defined the validator so that the ASP.Net engine knows before rendering the page that this particular validator also has a corresponding client-side validator.

Comment: Ahhh beautiful!! Works perfectly now! Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can mark this as the answer and close this thread :)